# How do I activate Pylance in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've been using the default VS Code extension for Python (Pylance) for quite some time, but one day I noticed that I wasn't getting the usual Intellisense. I tried changing to Jedi and it worked fine. However, I now want to switch back to Pylance because that's the one that most sites have information on when it comes to type hints.

I tried switching with this line:

```json
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

And got this error message:

[image: Error Message]

However, when I click on "Install Pylance", I get no message about any install and the issue is still present. I haven't disabled the Python extension at any point in this process, so I'm not sure why it says Pylance is not installed.

So how do I enable Pylance again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for [***Pylance***](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) in the extension panel and click **Install**

[image]

*This extension is included in the **Python** extension, you can also uninstall **Python** and reinstall it.*